# Are there pages that cannot be automated through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("chrome://settings")

advanced = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#advancedToggle > span")
advanced.click()
```

The above code doesn't work. To see where the advanced variable was referring to, you can go to paste "chrome://settings" in your browser (only works if you're using chrome) and scroll down to the bottom where you see the "Advanced" toggle.

That toggle even has an id `"advancedToggle"` but I can't seem to find anything on this page by any method (id, class, css, xpath).

> Is it possible that some pages are just automation-resistant (if
>   that's a proper term)? If so, is there any way to tell which pages
>   can't be automated on?

I've placed this last question in a block quote because this question was marked as a duplicate, but while the example has appeared somewhere else, I don't think there has been an answer for the question in the block...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `/deep/` to pass through `shadow-root` element:

```
body /deep/ #advancedToggle > span
```

The code would be like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("chrome://settings")

advanced = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body /deep/ #advancedToggle > span")
advanced.click()
```

Shadow-root element looks like this:

[image: img]

you can find it by pressing `F12` and then switch to `Elements` tab. Then in the DOM you will find `shadow-root`.

Comment: thanks! but how do I know whether a page has the `shadow-root` element? I don't seem to see `shadow-root` in the page source. Sorry if this question seems rather elementary!

Comment: I have added a screenshot and explanation. Note: not every page has shadow-root elements.

Comment: I couldn't find it using the Ctrl+F tool so thanks for the screenshot!